# Draw on surfaceView

Tags: android, crop

I want to crop the image before capturing it just like google goggle does.
I may have to draw a rectangle for that and then add a onTouchListener.
But I am not able to figure out how to draw a rectangle on the surfaceView that we use for Camera preview.

Is there any source I can look into as a guide on how to about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are not using the camera intent.
You should override `protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)` in your SurfaceView to be able to use `canvas.canvas.drawRect(...)` in this method.

If you do use the camera intent you have to basically capture the image, set it as background and then override onDraw.

Comment: Ok. I got it! Thanks. I have a class which extends View and I have onDraw overridden in that. And I am now creating an instance of this class in my camera activity and I see the rectangle.